# writing test for angular.js directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am having problems with writing tests for this the angular.js directive which checks if the name from input is a full name:

here is the directive:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('fullName', [
  function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {

          if (value.split(' ').length >= 2) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('fullName', true);
            return value;
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('fullName', false);
            return value;
          }

        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

here is a nonworking and unfinished test:

```
 describe('example directive test', function() {

  beforeEach(module('app.directives'));


  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
     elm = angular.element(
       '<label for="user_name" class="field">' +
         '<input' +
           'required' +
           'ng-class="{error: showErr && signupForm.name.$invalid}"' +
           'full-name' +
           'name="name"' +
           'id="user_name"' +
           'type="text"' +
           'autocomplete="off"' +
           'ng-model="user.name"' +
           'placeholder="Full Name" />' +
         '<span class="error" ng-show="showErr && signupForm.name.$invalid">Please enter your full name.</span>' +
       '</label>');

     scope = $rootScope;
     $compile(elm)(scope);
     scope.$digest();

  }));


  it('should have a working full-name directive', function() {
    var input = elm.find('input');
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.name = "Johnsmith"
    });
    expect(input.eq(0)).hasClass("showErr").toBeTruthy();
  });


});
```

right now my code is throwing error "TypeError: undefined is not a function" on last line by "hasClass("ShowError"). how can I make it work?

Comment: looks like a filter rather than a directive

Comment: hmm, you might be right, but it works, I just need to write tests for it. does it mean I can not test it this way?

Comment: "non working and unfinished test",you just didnt test anything. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB5b67Cg6bc, you're welcome.

Comment: nice video, but this directive is so much different and confusing. do you have any idea what i should do?

Comment: `expect(input.eq(0).hasClass("showErr")).toBeTruthy();` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

`hasClass` is not a property of the return value of `expect()`. Hence the `undefined is not a function`. Your code should be:

```
expect(input.eq(0).hasClass("showErr")).toBeTruthy();
```